# How do I load modules at startup in a certain order?

Tags: fedora, startup, modprobe

I have a group of modules that I need to be loaded at startup.  I've followed the [documentation for loading a module](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-kernel-modules-persistant.html) however I need load these modules in a certain order.

I've tried creating a bash script that uses a for loop and loads each module in the order I need.

```
mods=(mod1 mod2 mod3 ... modN)
for mod in $(mods); do
    if [ ! -c /dev/input/$mod ] ; then
        exec /sbin/modprobe $mod > /dev/null 2>&1
    fi
done
```

I've also tried creating a bash script that loads each module individually without at looping.

```
if [ ! -c /dev/input/mod1] ; then
        exec /sbin/modprobe mod1 > /dev/null 2>&1
fi

if [ ! -c /dev/input/mod2 ] ; then
        exec /sbin/modprobe mod2 > /dev/null 2>&1
fi

...

if [ ! -c /dev/input/modN ] ; then
        exec /sbin/modprobe modN > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

In both cases, only the first module is loaded, and none of the others.  Enabling more debugging out of the script (`#!/bin/sh -ex`) in both cases stops exactly at:

```
+ exec /sbin/modprobe mod1
```

I'm assuming that the system see that the first modules is correctly loaded and then terminates (but I'm not for sure on this).  How do I then load modules at startup in a specified order?

Comment: What modules are you loading exactly? In general modules *should* be loaded automagically as needed. I suspect there is nothing wrong with your script, but rather with you hardware and/or you may need to black list a (conficting) module. for example, I have similar problems at times when I use more then one wireless card (and I solve it by blacklisting one of the cards).

Comment: @bodhi.zazen these are custom kernal modules.  Also if I manually load these modules from the console without any issues.

Comment: OK. Why the custom modules? Are you running a custom kernel? hardware problem? So the modules load normaly, but your script fails? In that event, I suggest you remove the exec , just `/sbin/modprobe mod1`

Comment: As hildred points out, `exec` does the same thing in the shell that it does in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error is in your script.  Your for loop should look like this instead:

```
for mod in ${mods[@]}; do
```

The `{}` references the variable while `()` is for commands.  Second the `[@]` references the entire array.

Answer (score 2):

The exec command replaces the current shell with another command. It appears to be unnecessary in your case. If you do need it only use it on the last command.

Comment: removing `exec` doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: You also used the wrong parenthesis in your for statement. you wanted ${mods} not $(mods). the first does a variable substution, the second does command substution.

Comment: See my answer.  There's more than just that.